# String doesn't show when new line removed

Tags: c

So I use fgets to get strings from a file then add them to an array. But before I add them to the array, I want to strip the "\n". This is what I used for that

```
strtok(str,"\n");
array[i] = strdup(str);
```

array is initialized in
    char *array[32];

Now the functions work perfect, I can use the array and it's elements how I wan't to. However, whenever I try to print the elements, it doesn't work properly.

for example if `array[i] = hello`

```
printf("%s:TEST",array[i]);
```

will print

```
:TEST
```

but

```
printf("%s\n:TEST",array[i]);
```

will print

```
hello
:TEST
```

I need it to be on the same line, so I can't use \n, and it just weird how it will only print if there is a new line after it.

Edit: not strdup(strok) but strdup(str)

Edit: 
Complete example of code:

```
char *array[32]
char holder[32]


FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

int i = 0;

while(fgets(holder, 100, fp)){
    strtok(holder,"\n");
    array[i] = strdup(holder);
    i++;

}
fclose(fp);

printf("word: %s",words[1]);
```

array[i] will not print unless there is a '\n' after it, as mentioned above

Edit: added print function
text file is in format

```
string1
string2
string3
```

Comment: What is `array[i] = hello` supposed to do?

Comment: `strdup(strok)` - huh? `strtok` is a function. Please show [mcve].

Comment: `printf()` will not flush the output until it sees a new line character (or the internal output buffer of `printf()` becomes full) unless you explicitly flush the output. Check out `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: @RichardChambers True, but the described behavior is about having a *partial* output of `printf`

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `array[i] = strdup(str);` having used `strtok()` to truncate the input string. Anyway, here is a better way for [removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am commenting on "I need it to be on the same line, so I can't use \n, and it just weird how it will only print if there is a new line after it." from the post.

Comment: @RichardChambers the part that is missing is *before* `":TEST"` so it can't be a buffer flushing issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't say it was. Read the end of the post.

Comment: Without the MCVE it is guesswork. Perhaps the string contains a CR (carriage return) and so the first part is overwritten without a LF (line feed, newline) also being output. Function `strtok` was looking for `'\n'` but suppose the string contains `'\r'` instead. Try printing the value (with `%d` format spec) of each character in the string.

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry I mean strdup(str)

Comment: @WeatherVane I've tried using 'str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;' like the post says, but I get the same result.

Comment: One [mcve] worth hundreds of words. And your question is going to get closed without it anyway. So please, stop wasting our and your time and post one.

Comment: Please printf each character value of the string in decimal to see what it actually contains. I predict a `13` will be in there. And, please read every comment carefully.

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry, i've edited in a better example

Comment: Your edited code does not show the `printf` line. Note the "Complete" part of MCVE.

Comment: `dump(array, 8/*guessing*/);` and `void dump(void const *p, int n) { char unsigned const *x = p; while(n--) fprintf(stderr, " 0x%02x", *x++); }`

Comment: @EugeneSh. it is the same print function as above before the edit, and it prints the same way

Comment: *Complete example of code* -- it doesn't have the printing which is essential to the problem. Can you just "copy and paste" the exact code you are running?

Comment: Try `strtok(str, "\r\n");`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I've done that now

Comment: @WeatherVane works! thank you!

Comment: @WeatherVane seems like you nailed the problem. But this doesn't seem like the right solution, because `\r` could not be there and then the `strtok` wouldn't behave correctly. Could you perhaps write down a full answer which tokenizes on `\n` an removes the `\r` if it there at the end. Also explaining why there was a problem in the first place.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I can't: it's been put on hold and it does not seem right for me to abuse my privilege and re-open the question so I can post an answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane I voted to reopen at that time, because OP did add somewhat of an MCVE. I think it only needs one more right now.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya ah, I see now that I can only reopen a question I closed myself, as a duplicate.

Comment: @WeatherVane that seems fair!

Comment: duplicate: [printf without \n does not display text when placed before while(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7384110/995714), [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/995714), [why does "printf" not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39180642/995714)... But your example is still not compilable: `char *array[32] char holder[32]` doesn't work.

Comment: @YeeKee: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

The C library function char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim) breaks string str into a series of tokens using the delimiter delim. So it's not a function the treats the string as reference but as value. So when you do something like:

```
strtok(str, "\n");
```

str will have the same value as before. If you want the first token, as in, the str value until it finds "\n" for the first time, you have to do something like.

```
array[i] = strtok(str, "\n");
```

or

```
char *token = strtok(str, "\n");
array[i] = strdup(token);
```

or anything like that.

CODE:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  char buff[100];
  char *array[32];

  FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

  int i = 0;
  while(fgets(buff, 100, fp)){
    char* token = strtok(buff,"\n");
    array[i] = strdup(token);
    printf("%s:TEST\n", array[i]);
    i++;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return(0);
}
```

file.txt

```
HELLO
BYE
```

Output:

```
HELLO:TEST
BYE:TEST
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives the same result.

Comment: Your explanation is incorrect: `buff` is modified by `strtok` and the `'\n'` is overwritten with a `'\0'`, so using the return value of `strtok()` or `buff` should give the same behavior. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your have multiple problems in the code fragment posted:

- `array` is not *initialized* in `char *array[32]`, it is just defined this way and uninitialized if this definition occurs inside the body of a function. Incidentally, the `;` are missing from the definitions in the code fragment.
- the size of `holder` is `32`, yet you pass `100` to `fgets()` causing potential buffer overflows.
- `printf("%s:TEST",array[i]);` is not present in your code, you did not post the offending code.
- the final output, `printf("word: %s",words[1]);` uses an undefined object `words`, and the index `1` may be out of range if you only input a single word.

You must post the actual program with the offending behavior. The code fragment is inconsistent with the behavior you describe.