# Printf is not working in C signal handler

Tags: c, signals

Code in question first (minimized case):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int counter = 0;

void react_to_signal(int n) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Caught!\n");
    counter++;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    signal(SIGINFO, react_to_signal);

    while (1) {
        printf("%d\n", counter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I run the code, it loops as it should, printing out 0. Then in another shell..

```
kill -s SIGINFO <pid_of_my_process>
```

Signal is delivered, `c` is incremented .. but the `fprintf` doesn't happen.

Why is this so? In what environment/context does handler code run? Where can I read up on this?

Comment: Try to flush stderr using `fflush(stderr)`

Comment: Don't use printf() et.al. inside signal handlers. They are not signal safe (eg: can call malloc(), which is not signal-safe)

Comment: Amusingly, I could've sworn I'd tried a variant with `fflush` before I posted. Either never recompiled and ran, or shot myself in the foot with the infinite loop moving the message off screen. So unromantic and dumb.

Comment: How does `printf` use `malloc`/`free`? (What for?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In short: you cannot *safely* use `printf` within a signal handler.

There's a [list of authorized functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) in signal handler's man page. There is not `fprintf` in it.

That's because this function is not *reentrant*, mainly because it can use `malloc` and `free`.
See [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20201203085923/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-reent/index.html) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: In addition to potentially calling malloc/free (for buffer management), its internal buffer management is not reentrant, so if a signal occurs in the middle of a `printf` call, the `fprintf` call may end up corrupting the buffer in odd ways, leading to garbage or missed output.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to fflush stderr to get the message to write before the program exits.

Comment: Doesn't `printf` automatically flush when it reaches a newline?

Comment: No. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229096/does-printf-always-flush-the-buffer-on-encountering-a-newline

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the reentrancy problems, since `counter` is not volatile, its read might get hoisted out of the `while(1)` loop, leading to the printf in the loop always printing 0 even when the signal handler increments the global variable.