# Why do I get stack fault when handling these signals?

Tags: c, stack, signals, handler, fault

I have this solution for an exercise I was doing but when I try to run it
and send `SIGUSR1` the terminal shows "Stack fault", and I don't know why.

It shows nothing when I send `SIGUSR2`, but the thing is that with `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` the program works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void manejador(int signum){
    switch (signum){
    case SIGUSR1:
        printf("He recibido la señal SIGUSR1\n");
        break;
    case SIGUSR2:
        printf("He recibido la señal SIGUSR2\n");
        break;
    case SIGTERM:
        printf("Fin de ejecucion\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (signal(SIGUSR1, manejador) == SIG_ERR) {
    perror("error en la señal SIGUSR1");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (signal(SIGUSR2, manejador) == SIG_ERR) {
    perror("error en la señal SIGUSR2");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (signal(SIGTERM, manejador) == SIG_ERR) {
    perror("error en SIGTERM");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR) {
    perror("error en SIGINT");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while (1)
    pause();
}
```

Comment: Which operating system are you running this on ? Are you certain you have properly built/compiled this code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid using printf in a signal handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler)

Comment: and take also a look[at this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9547988/3436922)

Comment: I didn´t know this could be caused by printf. I´m running the last version of Debian @nos

Comment: from the man page for `signal()`  -- The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also var‐
       ied historically across different versions of Linux.   Avoid  its  use:
       use sigaction(2) instead.

Comment: the function: `perror()` outputs the system message that is currently associated with the variable `errno`,  probably not what you want.   Suggest using `write()` as that function can be safely used inside a signal handler; while `perror()` cannot be safely used inside a signal handler.

Comment: Thanks, I will always think about that tips. I was starting to believe all the solutions to signal exercises were wrong @user3629249