# Why I can't use I/O in POSIX signal handing?

Tags: c, unix, network-programming

I recently read code in unp(),in chp 5.9, on the book, when handling zombies, the author use

> signal(SIGCHLD, sig_chld);

Also, inside the sig_chld, the code is as following:

```
void sig_chld(int signo){
    pid_t pid;
    int stat;
    pid = wait(&stat);
    printf("child %d terminated\",pid); 
    return;
}
```

I have tried this, and I successfully handled zombies, but the function printf can't work normally.
Why?
If more information is needed, just comment.
Thanks!!!

Comment: you shouldn't be using `printf()` inside signal handler `sig_chld` as they are not signal safe. Between `\ ` --> `\n` inside `printf()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printf is not working in C signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547949/printf-is-not-working-in-c-signal-handler). Also read [How to avoid using printf in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler)

Comment: ok, man. I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only async-signal safe functions can be used in a signal handler. See the explanation and the list of such functions in [man signal-safety](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: And even most of those cannot be used safely since they set `errno`, causing error code loss.

Comment: @StaceyGirl You can save `errno` and restore it at the end of the signal handler.

Comment: thanks, man. I'm going to see it

Comment: Since `errno` is of type `int` rather than `volatile sig_atomic_t` I suspect that accessing it in both normal code and signal handlers is *technically* undefined behavior, though I suspect that even on a machine where `int` is not inherently written atomically it would be very difficult for a (non explicitly malicious) compiler to cause this undefined behavior to express itself.

Comment: @EOF `errno` shows its age, but still works as expected, and I see no reason why it wouldn't.