# Stack frame info / Back trace printing inside the program instead of using GDB

Tags: c, linux, stack, gdb, printstacktrace

we have requirement to "print Back trace info inside the program" if there is issue of SIGSEGV .
Based on set of links provided in stack overflow
I am using "backtrace_symbols_fd()"  with print_trace() function

```
void print_trace() {
    char pid_buf[30];
    sprintf(pid_buf, "%d", getpid());
    char name_buf[512];
    name_buf[readlink("/proc/self/exe", name_buf, 511)]=0;
    int child_pid = fork();
    if (!child_pid) {
        dup2(2,1); // redirect output to stderr
        fprintf(stdout,"stack trace for %s pid=%s\n",name_buf,pid_buf);
        execlp("gdb", "gdb", "--batch", "-n", "-ex", "thread", "-ex", "bt", name_buf, pid_buf, NULL);
        abort(); /* If gdb failed to start */
    } else {
        waitpid(child_pid,NULL,0);
    }
}
```

It is not printing the print_trace() info inside the program , it is just printing the SIGSEGV message
& signal no.

Can you please suggest what is going wrong inside

Comment: "I am using backtrace_symbols_fd()" - no, you are not using it.

Comment: @ks1322 : using backtrace_symbols_fd() in the signal handler function, once backtrace_symbols_fd () is called , next stamen tent it prints  print_trace() function.

Comment: You can't safely use `fprintf()` in signal handler function, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9547949/72178.

Comment: If the segmentation violation was due to a stack overflow, print_trace might not be able to allocate those char arrays. If that's the case, it might be worth using `sigaltstack`.