# C++11 thread detach

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

This setup

```
void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, Thread!\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void foo()
{
    std::thread t(run);
    t.detach();
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    getchar();
}
```

Gives me no output *until* I press enter (getchar returns and program ends, but I can see the output for a short while). However, when use the out commented line from foo, the output is shown directly. (Even after foo returns.) I'm using the VS11 beta version.
Which behavior is required here according to the standard?

Comment: Is the output buffered for each thread maybe?

Comment: Hm.. I tried std::endl, got an assert, switched the lines so that the new thread first waits one second and then makes the output, and hey, it works. Funny. So the output stream couldn't be initialized fast enough or what is going on there?

Comment: I think writing to standard output and reading from standard input are serialized operations.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't really know what that means. Any links? :)

Comment: You could try `std::sync_with_stdio(false);`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374264/is-cout-synchronized-thread-safe - The answer here says, that streams are thread safe. I think, that @R.MartinhoFernandes meant this.

Comment: I've tested this on GNU/Linux and works perfectly. It outputs "Hello, Thread!" once every second. Are you using windows?

Answer (score 4):

`"\n"` doesn't flush the output buffer. You need to use `std::endl` instead which flushes the buffer.

```
void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, Thread!"<<std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `std::flush` to manually flush the cout buffer

Comment: And you could try reading all the answers and comments that were already given. :p

Comment: And you could try confirming an answer so everyone knows that your question was answered :p

Answer (score -5):

I think this is because you are using std::cout, whick is buffered. Try with std::cerr.

Comment: This is not the reason. For example this code works with GCC under Linux. std::cout buffer is flushed at a newline character.

Comment: @Rafał Rawicki: I don't think your statement about the newline character is true. std::cout is flushed if you use std::endl, not if you just use the \n character. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Comment: In this context this statement is true, but flushing at the newline is not a general rule, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229096/does-printf-always-flush-the-buffer-on-encountering-a-newline

Comment: It's true that `cout` is buffered, but replacing it with `cerr` is a poor "solution" because it's not the same stream, and `stderr` could be redirected elsewhere or closed. A better solution is just to flush `cout`.