# Why does this hang without first printing?

Tags: c++, c, clang

Why does this hang without first printing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    printf("hello world");
    while (1) {}
}
```

Comment: Try adding a new line to it. Probably it hangs because the stdout isn't flushed yet.

Comment: still, try another compiler if yours accept `void main()` for C/C++.

Comment: actually you may try the result of `#include <stdio.h> int main(void){printf("hello"); fprintf(stderr, "world\n");}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you haven't flushed the standard output.  Try [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush).  Even better, for C++ use...

```
std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
```

Separately, you'd have a better chance of it flushing itself if you added a `\n`, but not all implementations follow the Standard when it comes to such things.

Comment: Do either the C or the C++ standards require that `\n` flushes the stream?

Comment: No, it´s only a common behaviour.

Comment: @user657267: the standards says `stdout` can be in line buffered or unbuffered mode, with the former being the default when connected to an interactive terminal (as the user probably wants to see the output in a timely fashion), and the latter used when output's written to a file, pipe etc. as that's more efficient.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229096/does-printf-always-flush-the-buffer-on-encountering-a-newline) for citations.  With C++ iostreams, `cout` - by default - flushes before input from `cin`, ensuring the user sees the relevant prompts... they're *"tied"* streams.

Comment: @TonyD Thank you. I looked it up myself in the meantime and found: `What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.` so technically it doesn't seem to be mandated.

Answer (score 3):

Call `fflush(stdout);` after `printf`.

This will force the stdout buffer to be flushed and printed.