# Why is stdout buffering?

Tags: c, libuv

I am trying to learn the `libuv` api and wrote the following test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uv.h>

void timer_cb(uv_timer_t* timer) {
    int* i = timer->data;
    --*i;
    if(*i == 0) {
       uv_timer_stop(timer);
    }
    printf("timer %d\n", *i);
    //fflush(stdout);
}

int main() {
    uv_loop_t* loop = uv_default_loop();
    uv_timer_t* timer = malloc(sizeof(uv_timer_t));
    uv_timer_init(loop, timer);
    int i = 5;
    timer->data = &i;
    uv_timer_start(timer, timer_cb, 1000, 2000);

    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    printf("Now quitting.\n");
    uv_close(timer, 0);
    uv_loop_close(loop);

    return 0;
}
```

When  run it, no output is displayed until the program finishes running, and then all the output is displayed at once. If I uncomment the `fflush` line it works as expected, writing every 2 seconds.

Can someone please explain this to me? Why is `stdout` not flushed after the newline, as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716621/331785) and in other places? Why do I need tomanually flush it?

Comment: "Why is stdout buffering" - Why not?

Comment: This answer may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5229135/868691

Comment: @AndrewHenle Windows, with mingw64 on msys

Comment: @Olaf I understood (see answer I linked to at the end) that the buffer flushes on a newline

Comment: @baruch: Where did you find that **in the standard**?

Comment: @LPs I tried that. Didn't help

Comment: @LPs As I said in the comments to the answers, I already tried that

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Take a look at [this forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156519/)

Comment: `stdout` is usually line buffered *if* output is going to a terminal.  If it is going to a file, it is usually *not* line buffered.

Comment: Funny, it works as expected with gcc 10.2.0,  target x86_64-pc-msys, Windows 10. Works started from mintty as well as Windows Console. Only **if I pipe it (e.g. to cat)** it fully buffers, consistent with the fact that the pipe is not a tty. Do you run the program from an IDE that displays the output in a widget that does not pretend to be a Console? (For what it's worth, an equivalent program with Windows Sleep() built as debug, run from VS, output in a Console Window, also uses linebuffering, so it's clearly not a Windows issue.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stream buffering is implementation-defined.

Per **7.21.3 Files**, paragraph 3 of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> When a stream is
> *unbuffered*, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the destination   as   soon   as   possible.    Otherwise   characters
> may   be   accumulated   and transmitted to or from the host
> environment as a block.  When a stream is
> *fully buffered*, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a  buffer  is  filled.   When  a
> stream  is
> *line  buffered*,  characters  are  intended  to  be transmitted  to  or  from  the  host  environment  as  a  block  when  a  new-line
> character  is encountered.  Furthermore, characters are intended to be
> transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is
> filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when
> input  is  requested  on  a  line  buffered  stream  that  requires
> the  transmission  of characters    from    the    host
> environment.     **Support    for    these    characteristics    is
> implementation-defined**, and may be affected via the `setbuf` and
> `setvbuf` functions.

The type of buffering is dependent on your implementation, and your implementation apparently isn't line-buffering in your example.

Comment: I set it to line buffering with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);` and it still doesn't work. Only if I set it to no buffering (`_IONBF`) does it work

Comment: As linked in that answer, on Windows there is no line buffering. I assume that is the issue
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86cebhfs.aspx#Anchor_3

Answer (score 7):

There is no strict requirement, that `stdout` is line buffered. It may be fully buffered as well (or not buffered at all), in which case `\n` does not trigger to flush the stream.

C11 (N1570) 7.21.3/7 *Files*:

> As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered;
>   the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if
>   and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an
>   interactive device.

C11 (N1570) 5.1.2.3/7 *Program execution*:

> What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.

You could try to force specific type of buffering by `setvbuf` standard function. For instance, to set line buffering for `stdout`, you may try with:

```
setvbuf(stdout, buff, _IOLBF, size);
```

where `buff` is declared as character array of `size` elements (e.g. 1024).

Note that `setvbuf` has to be called before any other I/O operation, that is performed to the stream.

Comment: I set it to line buffering with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);` and it still doesn't work. Only if I set it to no buffering (`_IONBF`) does it work

Comment: @baruch: AFAIR, `setvbuf` requires to supply it with self-prepared buffer. Otherwise, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, your system is deciding that your stdout is not interactive. Are you doing some strange redirect of stdout or doing something weird with your terminal? You should be able to override using setbuf or you can use stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12787815)

Comment: I think it includes 2 answers: use setvbuf or stderr. The third answer is only implied, to figure out why the system is mistaking stdout for non-interactive.