# Print order when using sync_with_stdio

Tags: c++, printf, cout

Look this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cout << "a";
    printf("b");
    std::cout << "c";
}
```

On gcc 9.2 I'm getting `acb` as output. I was expecting `bac`, because, if I understood correctly, `std::cout` would be using its buffer. Why was it printed in this order?

Additional question: setting `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)` would improve performance (in the above example, for instance)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <strike>default</strike> typical behaviour for the stdout stream is line buffering, so that output is perfectly reasonable. `printf` does not flush immediately, for that use `fflush(stdout)`.

To your second question, one would expect that performance is improved when synchronisation is not required. However, it is always better to profile and check, obviously for this small snippet, it won't much matter.

---

Edit: Answer corrected based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991116/why-is-stdout-buffering/37991361).