# Why doesn't `readline` return for `subprocess.stdout`?

Tags: python, subprocess, printf, stdout

I use Python `subprocess` to fork a C application and open a pipe to `stdout`.

```
app = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The application writes several lines to `stdout` like so:

```
printf("Line 0\n");
printf("Line 1\n");
printf("Line 2\n");
```

I try to read these lines in my Python script before the application exits:

```
line = app.stdout.readline()
```

However, `readline` blocks indefinitely without returning any content, even though I expect to read `Line 0`, `Line 1`, and `Line 2`, in three separate calls to `readline`. I notice that when the application finally exits, `readline` returns the expected contents. However, I want `readline` to return the expected contents as soon as they are passed to `printf`. What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229096/does-printf-always-flush-the-buffer-on-encountering-a-newline), `printf` only flushes its output on a newline when the output device is interactive (e.g., a terminal). **When the output device is non-interactive (e.g., a Python subprocess pipe, a file, etc.), `stdout` is fully buffered, so the output will only be flushed when the buffer is full, when `fflush(stdout)` is manually called, or when the buffer is otherwise forced to flush (e.g., on process exit).**

Thus, `readline` did not return because the application's `stdout` was never flushed, so `readline` had nothing to read. Changing the application code to this fixes the issue:

```
printf("Line 0\n");
printf("Line 1\n");
printf("Line 2\n");
fflush(stdout);  // New line
```

Others may wish to set the buffer mode of `stdout` with `setvbuf` rather than call `fflush`.

I was surprised by this because the common understanding of `printf` is that it flushes on a newline character, but this does not happen in all cases.

Comment: I think you have "non-interactive" and "interactive" mixed up in your answer. "interactive" means a terminal; "non-interactive" means a pipe.

Comment: Not only if it calls `fflush()`; also if it exits. That the program _isn't_ exiting is a detail that probably ought to be included in the question.

Comment: @jamesdlin Good catch! Fixed.